# Reading Multiple CSV Files into Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

The general use case behind the question is to read multiple CSV log files from a target directory into a single Python Pandas DataFrame for quick turnaround statistical analysis & charting. The idea for utilizing Pandas vs MySQL is to conduct this data import or append + stat analysis periodically throughout the day.

The script below attempts to read all of the CSV (same file layout) files into a single Pandas dataframe & adds a year column associated with each file read.

### The problem with the script is it now only reads the very last file in the directory instead of the desired outcome being *all* files within the targeted directory.

```
# Assemble all of the data files into a single DataFrame & add a year field
# 2010 is the last available year
years = range(1880, 2011)

for year in years:
    path ='C:\\Documents and Settings\\Foo\\My Documents\\pydata-book\\pydata-book-master`\\ch02\\names\\yob%d.txt' % year
    frame = pd.read_csv(path, names=columns)

    frame['year'] = year
    pieces.append(frame)

# Concatenates everything into a single Dataframe
names = pd.concat(pieces, ignore_index=True)

# Expected row total should be 1690784
names
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 33838 entries, 0 to 33837
Data columns:
name      33838  non-null values
sex       33838  non-null values
births    33838  non-null values
year      33838  non-null values
dtypes: int64(2), object(2)

# Start aggregating the data at the year & gender level using groupby or pivot
total_births = names.pivot_table('births', rows='year', cols='sex', aggfunc=sum)
# Prints pivot table
total_births.tail()

Out[35]:
sex     F   M
year        
2010    1759010     1898382
```

Comment: What type of object is `pieces`?  Is it a list or a dataframe?

Answer (score 13):

The `append` method on an instance of a DataFrame does not function the same as the `append` method on an instance of a list.  `Dataframe.append()` does not occur in-place and instead returns a new object.

```
years = range(1880, 2011)

names = pd.DataFrame()
for year in years:
    path ='C:\\Documents and Settings\\Foo\\My Documents\\pydata-book\\pydata-book-master`\\ch02\\names\\yob%d.txt' % year
    frame = pd.read_csv(path, names=columns)

    frame['year'] = year
    names = names.append(frame, ignore_index=True)
```

or you can use `concat`:

```
years = range(1880, 2011)

names = pd.DataFrame()
for year in years:
    path ='C:\\Documents and Settings\\Foo\\My Documents\\pydata-book\\pydata-book-master`\\ch02\\names\\yob%d.txt' % year
    frame = pd.read_csv(path, names=columns)

    frame['year'] = year
    names = pd.concat(names, frame, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, @gjreda. I used your method 1 provided & the desired outcome was perfect.

Comment: In [3]:
    # Expected row total should be 1690784

    names

    Out[3]:

    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    Int64Index: 1690784 entries, 0 to 1690783
    Data columns:
    births    1690784  non-null values
    name      1690784  non-null values
    sex       1690784  non-null values  
year      1690784  non-null values
dtypes: int64(2), object(2)

Answer (score 0):

I could not get either one of the above answers to work. The first answer was close, but the line space between the second and third lines after the `for` weren't right. I used the below code snippet in Canopy. Also, for those who are interested... this problem came from an example in ["Python for Data Analysis"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449319793). (An enjoyable book so far otherwise)

```
import pandas as pd

years = range(1880,2011)
columns = ['name','sex','births']
names = pd.DataFrame()

for year in years:
    path = 'C:/PythonData/pydata-book-master/pydata-book-master/ch02/names/yob%d.txt' % year
    frame = pd.read_csv(path, names=columns)
    frame['year'] = year
    names = names.append(frame,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: The example is on pp.33-34 of Python for Data Analysis - & the example uses pd.concat

Answer (score -3):

remove the line space between:

```
    frame = pd.read_csv(path, names=columns)
```

&

```
    frame['year'] = year
```

so it reads

```
    for year in years:
        path ='C:\\Documents and Settings\\Foo\\My Documents\\pydata-book\\pydata-book-master`\\ch02\\names\\yob%d.txt' % year
        frame = pd.read_csv(path, names=columns)
        frame['year'] = year
        names = pd.append(names, frame, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: The blank line has no effect in Python code.  It could only have an effect if you were pasting lines into a console or something.